# strcmp doesn't seem to work

Tags: string, array, c-string

I'm trying to compare a char array that I'm assembling to a string and I'm having trouble comparing the strings.

I'm getting the data for the char array as a set of bytes and I'm compiling it into a char array like this:

```
void messageHandler(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length)
{
  char buffer[length];
  for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
  {
    buffer[i] = (char)payload[i];
  }
```

So grabbing each of the ASCII codes and converting it into a character as I add it to the buffer.

After I do that I'm trying to print the buffer to the monitor and then compare it to a string. Though it's not working:

[image]

I know I'm getting all of those extra characters in the println b/c the buffer doesn't end in `0` so print keeps reading out memory bytes till it hits the zero, but I don't know why `strcmp` isn't showing the buffer matching the string `"ravenclaw"`.

I'm sure it's for the same "missing the null terminator" issue, but I'm not sure how to fix it. Help is appreciated!!

Comment: Either I don't understand your question or you're on the verge of answering it yourself.

Comment: It would be better if you put the code into your question as text, not a as a screen capture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to already understand that it's not null-terminated and that's why it's not working the way you expect.  So, I'll take a different tact for "how to fix it".

You can simply not treat the payload as a string, and instead use `memcmp`, as in:

```cpp
if (length == 9 && memcmp(payload, "ravenclaw", 9) == 0) {
```

`memcmp` behaves similarly to `strcmp`, except that it isn't looking for a null terminator. It just compares however many bytes (chars) you specify.  In practice you may want to use a variable to hold "ravenclaw" and to strlen() on it rather than specifying the length separately as I've done above, e.g.:

```cpp
static const char ravenclaw[] = "ravenclaw";
static const size_t ravenclaw_len = sizeof ravenclaw - 1;
if (length == ravenclaw_len && memcmp(payload, ravenclaw, ravenclaw_len) == 0) {
```

or any number of variations on that which might use `strlen()`, or a pointer rather than array (if not using `sizeof`) or `PROGMEM` with `strlen_P()` and `memcmp_P()` or... etc, etc, possibly putting this into a function so you can reuse it.

---

As a side note, if you know payload contains non-null-terminated text that you want to print, you can use the overload of `write()` that allows you to specify the length.

```cpp
Serial.write(payload, length);
```

Comment: Ah awesome, thanks for the extra detail. I wasn't aware of `memcmp`. That def seems like a better way of doing the comparison.

Answer (score 2):

The easier way to simply the code is to use `strcpy` to create a buffer that is 1 byte longer than the `length` and then terminate it with `\0`.

```
void messageHandler(char *topic, byte *payload, unsigned int length) {
  char buffer[length+1];
  strcpy(buffer, (const char*) payload);
  buffer[length] = '\0';

  Serial.println(buffer);

  int matched = strcmp(buffer, "ravenclaw");
}
```

Comment: oh nice! I like this take on it. TBH I thought I tried this at one point and it didn't work, though I was noodling a lot at the time so I may have jacked up my code. thanks for the tip!

Comment: Ah, the snag in this one is that after casting to a const char pointer you can't add anything to it. You end up with a `invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char',  buffer[length] = "\0"` error.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz, what you seem to have missed is that in their code they used `'\0'` rather than `"\0"`, single rather than double quote.  The terminator is a single character being written into a single character of an array of characters.  It *should* compile any Arduino using g++, which is to say all of them that I know of; the run-time-sized local array is making use of a g++ extension.

Comment: @ChrisSchmitz However, if you want to try this way of doing it, **you need to swap out the `strcpy()` line  and replace it with `memcpy(buffer, payload, length);`**  Otherwise the `strcpy` may overflow `buffer`, because the payload is, again, not terminated.  So there's nothing to tell `strcpy` to stop, except the next `'\0'` it finds in memory following `payload`.